# Duplicate rows using Hibernate with large Datasets

Tags: hibernate, hql, large-data

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220835/hql-select-where-row-appears-more-than-once) about how to query duplicate rows in a DB. The answer I received worked and was much quicker, but I have expanded the dataset from 20,000 rows to 80,000 rows and the time taken by the query is in minutes, which is not acceptable.

If I have a table like this:

```
ID    Name    Country
1     Dave    UK
2     Jim     UK
3     Dave    UK
4     Dave    US
5     Jim     US
```

I want to be able to return rows 1 and 3, because they are the only rows where the combination of name and country appears more than once.

The current answer was to do the following:

```
select r 
from Runner r  
where exists
(
    select rn
    from Runner rn
    where rn.id <> r.id 
    and rn.name = r.name
    and rn.country = r.country
)
```

But this is taking far too long. I was wondering if anyone is able to optimise this query to be more efficient in the comparison, or if there are any strategies for dramatically improving the query performance?

Answer (score 0):

It need not be a sub-query.

How about the following query

select name, country, count(1)
from Runner 
group by name, country
having count(1) > 1

Based on the revised needs, you may use this:

```
select * 
from Runner r1 
inner join ( 
    select name, country, count(1) 
    from Runner 
    group by name, country 
    having count(1) > 1) r2 on (r1.name = r2.name and r1.country = r2.country)
where r1. name = ?
```

The where clause for the overall query is only an example, if you want to limit the results.

Comment: I attempted something similar to this and it threw an error because there was no ID in the group by clause.

Comment: Please try it query browser. If you are not including id in the query, it need not be included in the group by clause

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to return just the name and the country. I want to return the entire object, which will implicitly include the ID.

Comment: The following should give you all the columns of all the rows of all duplicate name and country combination; and that includes id. Feel free to add where clause to the outer query:

select *
from Runner r1
 inner join (
  select name, country, count(1)
  from Runner 
  group by name, country
  having count(1) > 1) r2 on (r1.name = r2.name and r1.country = r2.country)

Comment: Can you edit this into your answer? I will try it on Monday and will respond with the query.